# how to call knative service [grpc server] by using a python client

Tags: grpc-python, knative, istio-gateway, knative-serving

I have created a knative service[gRPC server] in  **aks cluster**, I have exposed the service using istio gateway private static IP,

After using the command **kubectl get ksvc** I have got an address **sample-app.test.10.153.157.156.sslio.io**

When I try to use this address in the python client, it throws error saying failed to connect addresses, but if I try to hit the service using
**curl sample-app.test.10.153.157.156.sslio.io** I am able to hit the service, I don't know what i am missing here.. please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRPC uses HTTP/2. You may need to explicitly name your port `h2c`. I'm assuming that you've tested the container locally without Knative in the path and have been able to make a grpc call in that case.